# Regexp on nmap services file

Tags: regex, sed, nmap

I need to filter with sed only the ports from /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services

```
tcpmux  1/tcp   0.001995        # TCP Port Service Multiplexer [rfc-1078]
compressnet     2/tcp   0.000013        # Management Utility
compressnet     3/tcp   0.001242        # Compression Process
unknown 4/tcp   0.000477
unknown 6/tcp   0.000502
echo    7/tcp   0.004855
unknown 8/tcp   0.000013
discard 9/tcp   0.003764        # sink null
unknown 10/tcp  0.000063
systat  11/tcp  0.000075        # Active Users
```

I've tryed something like (!?([0-9]+/tcp))
But it wont work: why?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
grep -oP '\d+(?=/(udp|tcp))' /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services
```

or with perl :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if m!\d+(?=/(udp|tcp))!' /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services
```

I use a *positive look ahead* advanced regex, see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

or with awk without advanced regex :

```
awk '{gsub("/.*", ""); print $2}' /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services
```

or

```
awk -F'[ /\t]' '{print $2}' /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services
```

Comment: wont work.. 
i've partially restrict the problem with 
cat /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services | grep '[0-9]/tcp'

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using AWK

```
cat /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F\/ '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is so:

```
cut -s -d\  -f2 test
```

You can also do it so:

```
sed '/[^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/ s::\1:; /^$/d' FILE
```

`cut` variant prints empty lines for non-matching.